# it is nessesary to have a server in order to let the users interact in android application?

Tags: java, android

I'am wondering if there is a way to make a peer-to-peer or phone to phone connection, lets say is a chat room or a game online, it is required to have a server that accepts socket connections or is there an easy way to do this? I'am talking about android phone-to-phone application via sockets, cause I don't know where can I get a free java server to make this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably host a server instance on one of the phones, have that phone connect to itself, and have the other phone connect to the hosting phone. This way would also allow for multiple phones to connect to eachother.

Comment: but this host phone have to have a static IP adress right?

Comment: @Kjelkor Its IP should remain the same for the session you'll be playing in. But the other person connecting will have to know the current IP of the host. It's possible the IP will change if its not static when you're disconnecting and then try to play a new game the next day for example (then the other person will need the new IP address again).

Comment: and looks like the person will have to type manually that IP...cause there is now way to make it automatically?

Comment: @Kjelkor I don't think so unless you use a server

Comment: @Kjelkor There may be a way (and I have no experience with this so I have no idea if its possible, but it could be) to find the other users of the network you're currently connected to, so if 2 users are on the same network, they might be able to view the LAN if someone is hosting. Could be something you want to look into, but of course this is only possible if both users are no the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't done any android programming i've been playing a game that does this through either wifi, or bluetooth...

I can't help you with code or anything but here's a link to the designer's blog

http://www.sleepingbeastgames.com/blog/

I answered in an answer because I can't comment yet :(